# Call Python from Matlab 2017 with options

Tags: python, matlab

It's straightforward to call the Python KS test from MATLAB:

```
foo = py.scipy.stats.ks_2samp(rand(1,50),rand(1,70));
```

But when I call the Anderson-Darling k-sample test this way I get one error:

```
bar = py.scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp(rand(1,50),rand(1,70));
"Python Error: AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0"
```

and this way results in another error (here, I'm trying to set midrank = false, thinking that might be the cause of the previous error)

```
bar = py.scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp(rand(1,50),rand(1,70),false);
bar = py.scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp(rand(1,50),rand(1,70),'false');
bar = py.scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp(rand(1,50),rand(1,70),'midrank=false');
"Python Error: TypeError: anderson_ksamp() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"
```

I've read https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html as well as older questions about calling Python from Matlab, but the older questions do not apply to the current API.
Question 1: How do I call anderson_ksamp in MATLAB?
Question 2: How do I change the significance level of this test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got you function arguments wrong.

`ks_2samp` [expects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html#scipy.stats.ks_2samp) to receive two vectors of variables, so you are good there.

`anderson_ksamp` [expects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp.html) to receive a **series** of vectors:

> **scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp** (samples, midrank=True)
>
> samples : sequence of 1-D array_like
>
> Array of sample data in arrays.

So, you should create a cell array, where each cell is a vector of samples, and pass it as a first argument, since your samples could have different dimensions.

If you want to test that two vectors come from the same distribution, you should use regular `anderson` test, which is very similar to Kolmogorov-Smirnov 2 sample test. Just concatenate the values and send it in as a single vector.

As for significance levels, you can not change them. They are predefined and calculated (at least) for 10%, 5%, 2.5% and 1% levels. It is enough for any practical purpose.

Comment: Since Python 3.9, this [gives the following error](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/638735-matlab-numpy-array-attributeerror-array-array-object-has-no-attribute-fromstring):  `Python Error: AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'fromstring'`  Would anyone know how to fix this?